# Python: Create function without recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I would like to create this function without recursion.

```
def fib2(n: int) -> int:
    if(n <= 0): return 0
    if(n <= 2): return n
    return ((fib2(n-1) * fib2(n-2)) - fib2(n-3))
```

Can anyone help me or explain how to solve this?

Comment: can you please provide expected output?

Comment: A recursive call repeats the same code, but with different arguments. So, you need a loop (to repeat the execution of the same code) and variables which hold values sent to the loop and results from the loop.

Comment: @ch2019 fib2(7) == 37

Comment: @barmar How is this a  duplicate?

Comment: Oh, I thought this was fibonacci, but it's some weird variation of it.

Comment: I've reopened, but I think the same principles in those answers can probably be used for this.

Comment: @Barmar Thnx and true, still this needs to keep track of 3, not 2 values, so  think it can have instructive answers in its own right that are not immediately obvious to the beginner.

Comment: Another question about fibonacci with last 3 numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921314/fibbonaci-like-sequence-of-last-3-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One rather concise and Pythonic way to do it without any extra space requirements:

```
def fib2(n: int) -> int:
    a, b, c = 0, 1, 2
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b, c = b, c, (c * b) - a
    return a
```

You need to keep track of three values for the calculation and just keep rotating through them.

Answer (score 0):

Find all the fib2 results from 1 to nn.

```
def fib2(nn: int) -> int:
  mem = {
    0: 0, # first  if
    1: 1, # second if
    2: 2  # second if
  }
  # now find all the fib2 results from 3 to nn
  kk = 3 
  while ( kk <= nn ) :
      mem[kk] = mem[kk-1] * mem[kk-2] - mem[kk-3] 
      kk++;
  return mem[nn]
```

Comment: Exercise to OP : you can do it in constant memory :-)